# use BERT word to vector embedding only on word, not sentence

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, word-embedding, data-preprocessing

How to use BERT word to vector embedding only on word, not sentence?

I have list of nouns and I need vector version of these words using BERT. I researched a lot on how to do it, but I could only achieve a result using SentenceTransformer, which is not a correct way to solve a problem.

Here is the example:
`embedder = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')`
`embeddings = embedder.encode(words).tolist()`

I got confused with the BertTokenizer and Vectorizer, while reseaching on the problem. They give me tensors or weird lists that i cannot further use for my problem, whereas I could easily use the output of SentenceTransformer.

Any help or recommendations would be very helpful!